# Difference between count() and sum() when finding NaN rows in table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, sum

I have this table, values,  - some of the values are NaN:

```
ID   Value1    Value2    Value3
12   "filled"  "filled"   NaN
13   "filled"  "filled"   "filled"
14   "filled"  "filled"   NaN
```

I have to find the total number of rows in Value3 that are missing -

My code is

```
values_missing = values["Value3"].isnull().count()
```

But this returns the total number of rows in the table, which is obviously wrong

Playing around, I have found that:

```
values_missing = values["Value3"].isnull().sum()
```

returns the correct answer, but I am struggling to understand why exactly

Why isn't count() used, when there is nothing to have the sum() of, just the number or rows?

Comment: you should check the documentation- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html.

Comment: To elaborate on the first comment, `Series.count` returns the "number of non-NA/null observations in the Series". So, you probably are meant to write `values.Value3.count()` in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `pandas.DataFrame.count` we have:

[image]

So in your case:

```
values["Value3"].isnull()

0     True
1    False
2     True
```

It gives us three non-NA occurrences. Then if you add `.count()` at the end, you get the total number which is 3.

When you add `.sum()` it sums True values for `.isnull()` function.

In your case:

```
values["Value3"].isnull().sum()

2

values["Value3"].notnull().sum()

1
```

Answer (score 0):

`values_missing = values["Value3"].isnull()` returns a pandas Series.
`count()` does count the number of values in the series.
`sum()` does summarize all the values where `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

[image]